# Read xml file from storage with WP8.1 StorageFile Api

Tags: xml, asynchronous, async-await, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

My application should read an xml file from storage using the `StorageFile API`. This has to be done async since he `StorageFile API` provides only `async` methods.

The Constructor calls the method `CallAsyncMethod()` which calls and (should) await the `LoadXmlFromStorageAsync` method.

The `DataAccess()` constructor does not wait for the `CallAsyncMethod()` and completes BEFORE the XML file is loaded. The `xmlData` variable is therefore not initialized when i call the `GetElement()` method. This is because the constructor does not wait for the async method to complete.

How can I fix this?

I guess i just don't get the async/await thing.

**usage of DataAccess class**

```
var dataAccess = new DataAccess();
dataAccess.GetElement("test"); //NullReferenceException
```

**DataAccess class**

```
public sealed class DataAccess
{
    private const string FileName = "data.xml";
    private const string FilePath = @"ms-appx:///Data/";
    private XDocument xmlData;

    public DataAccess()
    {
        //need to wrap this call, the async keyword does not work for construtor
        CallAsyncMethod();
    }

    private async void CallAsyncMethod()
    {
        await LoadXmlFromStorageAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadXmlFromStorageAsync()
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(string.Concat(FilePath, FileName)));

        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            this.xmlData = XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<XElement> GetElement(string nodeName)
    {
        //NullReferenceException because xmlData is not initializied yet
        return this.xmlData.Descendants(nodeName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your entire code. Clearly you're using the `thix.xmlData` field *before* the async code completes.

Comment: Yes, thats the point! It is because the async method does not block as they should. Therefore the end of the constructor is reached before the initialisation of the field this.xmlData is done. The error is somewhere in the code shown above & it has todo something with async/await.

Comment: You need to post the `DoSomethingWithTheLoadedXmlDocument()` implementation, or nobody can help you.

Comment: i posted the whole class now but i'm pretty sure that there has been a misunderstanding about the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you can't do what you're doing, unless you forcefully synchronize the code. However, I would recommend an alternative approach, where you await once `GetElement` is called (if it haven't been called previously). Of course, this is not a thread-safe solution.

```
public sealed class DataAccess
{
    private const string FileName = "data.xml";
    private const string FilePath = @"ms-appx:///Data/";
    private XDocument xmlData;

    public DataAccess()
    {
    }

    private async Task<XDocument> LoadXmlFromStorageAsync()
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(string.Concat(FilePath, FileName)));

        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            return XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<XElement>> GetElement(string nodeName)
    {
         if (this.xmlData == null)         
             this.xmlData = await LoadXmlFromStorageAsync();

         return this.xmlData.Descendants(nodeName).ToList();
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My application is really data centric, I have to load all the data before i can display anything. That's why i don't need async methods. This should happen while the splash screen is displayed. Async/await is like a virus, use it once in your application and you are nearly forced to use it everywhere. this seems a bit overkill for my purpose. Even if it feels so wrong, I guess i have to forcefully synchronize the code :/

Comment: Async/await is fine, it's just that most developers today are too ignorant to understand it.