# xml serialization and deserialization allowed in wp8.1?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1

I want to know if xml serialization and deserialization is available in windows phone application 8.1 c#?

If yes, how do I do it and if serialization is not permitted then can I do XDom manipulation on the xml file I am storing in the appdata's localfolder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(v=vs.110).aspx) is for this purpose, you open an `IsolatedStorageFileStream` and then use XmlSerializer to serialize the object into the stream. Check out code Sample from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268151/XML-Serialization-in-Windows-Phone-Tips-and-Tric).

If you want to manipulate the XML document directly, use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Read this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23316369/815938.

Comment: I will try and mark your reply as answer. Thanks for the guidance.